# Work around not being able to perform an aggregate within an aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select data in a column with the equation (row 11/sum(row 1))*row 2, but row 1 is already a summed value. Below are the two existing columns that I want to work with.

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(SUM(a), 'C') row 1,
    FORMAT(b, 'C') row 2
```

I tried

```
FORMAT((SUM(a) / SUM(SUM(a)) * b), 'C') row 3
```

but I get the error

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

How can I write this so I get the values I need?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), perhaps to could take a step back and explain what the full goal is here with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an `OVER` clause, in other words a window function. This is calculated *after* normal aggregation, so you can nest one inside the other.

```sql
FORMAT(
  SUM(a) / SUM(SUM(a)) OVER () * b,
  'C'
) AS row3
```

An empty `OVER ()` means you are calculating over the whole set of rows, without any partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your **inner** statement into a sub-query:

```
SELECT SUM(Cnt)
  FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS Cnt
          FROM sys.sysobjects
       ) a
```